# Use Case Statement in Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Hi every one  i want to use case statement in join using this query and got error

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SII.SIDATE,103)DATE,SII.SALEID,SII.ItemName,SI.TenancyID

FROM F_SALESINVOICEITEM SII
INNER JOIN F_SALESINVOICE SI ON  SI.SALEID=SII.SALEID 
INNER JOIN #TempTableSearch ts ON CASE
 WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = '1' THEN ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.TENANCYID
  WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='2' THEN ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.EMPLOYEEID
   WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='3' THEN ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.SUPPLIERID
    WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='4' THEN ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.SALESCUSTOMERID
```

Error

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IT should be,

```
ON 
ts.ACCOUNTID =  CASE
                    WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = '1' THEN SI.TENANCYID
                    WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = '2' THEN SI.EMPLOYEEID
                    WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = '3' THEN SI.SUPPLIERID
                    WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = '4' THEN SI.SALESCUSTOMERID
                END
```

Comment: What would happen if `ACCOUNTTYPE` was 5? Would the condition become `ts.ACCOUNTID = NULL`?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using CASE, I'd much rather do this:

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SII.SIDATE,103)DATE,SII.SALEID,SII.ItemName,SI.TenancyID
FROM F_SALESINVOICEITEM SII
INNER JOIN F_SALESINVOICE SI ON  SI.SALEID=SII.SALEID 
INNER JOIN #TempTableSearch ts ON
       (ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='1' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.TENANCYID)
    OR (ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='2' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.EMPLOYEEID)
    OR (ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='3' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.SUPPLIERID)
    OR (ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='4' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.SALESCUSTOMERID)
```

To explain why the query didn't work for you: the syntax of the `CASE` requires an `END` at the end of the clause. It would work, as the other solutions proposed suggest, but I find this version to be more convenient to understand - although this part is highly subjective.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this, so you have no chance to misspell something (note that `ACCOUNTTYPE` and `ACCOUNTID` used only when needed, you don't have to copy-paste it)

```
select
    convert(varchar(10), SII.SIDATE,103) as DATE,
    SII.SALEID, SII.ItemName, SI.TenancyID
from F_SALESINVOICEITEM as SII
    inner join F_SALESINVOICE as SI on SI.SALEID = SII.SALEID 
    outer apply (
        '1', SI.TENANCYID
        '2', SI.EMPLOYEEID
        '3', SI.SUPPLIERID
        '4', SI.SALESCUSTOMERID
    ) as C(ACCOUNTTYPE, ACCOUNTID)
    inner join #TempTableSearch as ts on
        ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = C.ACCOUNTTYPE and ts.ACCOUNTID = C.ACCOUNTID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error. You are missing `END` there.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that `CASE ... END` block is NOT equivalent to `IF { }` from C-like languages. Much rather this is equivalent to elaborate version of `... ? ... : ...` operator from C-like languages. What it means that the WHOLE `CASE` block must essentially evaluate to single value and that this value has to be the same type no matter which case of the block is executed. This means that:

```
CASE
WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = '1' THEN ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.TENANCYID ...
END
```

Is fundamentally incorrect unless you work on a version of database that will allow you bool value as a value (SQL Server won't allow it for example but I think some of MySQL version used to allow it - not sure about this). You probably should write something like:

```
CASE
WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE = '1' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.TENANCYID THEN 1
WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='2' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.EMPLOYEEID THEN 1
WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='3' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.SUPPLIERID THEN 1
WHEN ts.ACCOUNTTYPE='4' AND ts.ACCOUNTID=SI.SALESCUSTOMERID THEN 1
ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Notice how the whole `CASE` block evaluates to 1 or 0 and then it is compared to 1. Of course instead of 4 `WHEN`'s you could use one `WHEN` with combination of `AND`'s, `OR`'s and `( )` brackets. Of course in this particular case answer by @ppeterka 66 is correct as `CASE` is not suited for what you really wanted to do - I'm just trying to clarify what `CASE` really is.