# Mysql How to create columns name from select result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select result from different database based on a subsring value from columns.
Here is my table student:

```
Original_student        Other_student
1010173                   1240240
1010173                   1240249
```

The 3rd digit in the number will be used to distinguish database. for example. I want the query be

```
select original_student, Other_student, month
from student join database-(substring(other_student,3,1).payment
```

My question is: How can I concatenate the substring to a database name or column name dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sebas. But I am not sure how to concatenate database-(substring(other_student,3,1) is it correct?

Comment: what is the context? stored procedure? php?

Comment: Hi Sebas. It is stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a field to identify each student by a unique id (`id_student`), here is a cheap alternative:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_student_payment AS
SELECT 0 AS db, payment, id_student FROM database-0
UNION 
SELECT 1 AS db, payment, id_student FROM database-1
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS db, payment, id_student FROM database-2
UNION 
SELECT 3 AS db, payment, id_student FROM database-3
/* here you have to add all databases you're using. There's a little maintenance cost, for if one day there's a new database to be created this view would have to be modified */
;

SELECT 
    original_student, 
    Other_student, 
    month, 
    v.payment
FROM 
    student s
        JOIN v_student_payment v ON v.id_student = s.id_student AND v.db = SUBSTRING(other_student,3,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a Case statement for checking with the join. Try looking at this link

[Use Case Statement in Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979298/use-case-statement-in-join)